# Regular expression, replace whitespaces inside tag

Tags: java, regex

I have an incorrect xml string and I would like to build a correct one

```
<root val="yyy">
    <fol der val="attribute 1">myfolder</folder>
</root>
```

The problem is the white space inside tag: "fol der". 
It's possible to replace white spaces inside < > tags(but not inside attributes) using regular expression in java?
Thanks to all

Comment: Is it a one time problem with known elements or does it need to work with arbitrary input?

Comment: So you want `<folderval=...`? I don't think so.

Comment: If you replaced the white space inside the `<` and `>` tags would it not become <rootval="yyy"> and <folderval="attribute1"> ?

Comment: Please specify on WHERE in the tags you want it replaced. Only the first one?

Comment: I just want to remove the blank in tag <folder>. I see somthing similar but it seems not working well: "(?=<[^=]+?>)(?=</?\w+\s+\w+)(<.*?)(\s+)(.*?>)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is like this:

```
<root val="yyy">
    <fo l der val="attribute 1">myfol d er</folder>
</root>
```

Following should work:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=<).*?(?=/?>|\\s*\\w+\\s*=)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data); // your XML
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().replace(" ", ""));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
data = sb.toString();
System.out.println(data);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<root val="yyy">
    <folder val="attribute 1">myfol d er</folder>
</root>
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/TIrsQR

Answer (score 2):

I would have used `(?<=[<]\w*)\s+` but java's regex engine doesn't support quantifiers in lookbehind..

You would have to do this if there are multiple spaces.

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(?<=[<])(/?)\\s*(\\w*)\\s+(?!\\w+\\s*=)").matcher(xml);
while(m.find())
{
    xml=m.replaceAll("$1$2");
    m.reset(xml);   
}
```

---

Though this won't work for attribute names

Comment: wow, we are close to the solution! this regex replace only the first space, how to replace more than one? for example: <fo l der>

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but this is a wrong tool for solving the wrong problem. The rule of thumb is, do not try to parse/process XML files yourself with regular expressions. If you got an incorrect/invalid XML, that is the problem you should be solving with the one who provided it, not how to fix it.