# RegEx Help - How to remove space inside html tags?

Tags: regex

I have html code inside txt files.

There are some mistakes in some html tags

The trailing html tag often have white space, like these

```
</ p> 
</p >
</ div>
< /div>
</ h1>
```

How can I use RegEx code to remove all space inside the angel bracket?
So the above becomes:

```
</p>
<div>
<h1>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this answer will do what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095106/regular-expression-replace-whitespaces-inside-tag

Comment: Thanks for the link, on that page, it has the following RegEx code 
(?s)(?<=<).*?(?=/?>|\\s*\\w+\\s*=)      

I tried it but it does not work
https://regex101.com/r/43a61h/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course regex doesn’t “do” anything to the input, for that you need a tool/app code, however try this:

```
Search: <\s*/\s*(\w+)\s*>
Replace: </$1>
```

The tag name is captured in the regex as group 1 and put back in the replacement, but with preceding spaces removed.

Comment: It says pattern error here when I use the following code
<\s*/\s*(\w+)>
https://regex101.com/r/43a61h/5

Comment: @stackmike there’s nothing wrong with the pattern. Regex101 requires forward slashes to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: I now tried again in Atom with code <\s*/\s*(\w+)>
It indeed works, it removes space from < /p> or < /h1> or < /div>
But if there is one with like < /div > or < /div >, it won't replace it.
Could you advise the code to remove even when the last > has a space before it? (like in < /div >

Comment: You didn’t include such examples. I edited the regex to work with those too.

Comment: I tried in Notepad++, it works fine now, even < /div > get trimmed to </div>. Thank you